# How to show correct answers in RadioButton using Javascript

Tags: forms, javascript, acrobat

I need to show the correct answers when clicking on the (Show Answers) button and entering the correct password.

To do this, select the correct answer in the radiobutton for which (true).

I use MikTeX PDFLatex (JavaScript) and Acrobat Reader.

Thanks in advance.

WME:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, latexsym, mathtext}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=20mm, right=20mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%----------------------------
\usepackage[pdftex]{eforms}
\everyRadioButton{}
%
\newcounter{nvopr}
\newcommand{\VOPRN}{\addtocounter{nvopr}{1}\arabic{nvopr}}%
%
\makeatletter
%
\renewcommand{\alph}[1]{\asbuk{#1}}
\setenumerate[1]{label=\arabic*), nosep, leftmargin=1.55\parindent, labelindent=\parindent, labelsep=*}
\setenumerate[2]{label=\theenumi\arabic*), nosep, leftmargin=\parindent,  listparindent=\parindent}
\makeatother
%----------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \LARGE Test\ldots
\end{center}

\VOPRN. The application of the information system implements?
\par\bigskip \radioButton{button\arabic{nvopr}}{10bp}{10bp}{false} secure storage of information;
\par\medskip \radioButton{button\arabic{nvopr}}{10bp}{10bp}{false} performing application-specific transformations of information and calculations;
\par\medskip \radioButton{button\arabic{nvopr}}{10bp}{10bp}{false} providing users with a convenient interaction interface;
\par\medskip \radioButton{button\arabic{nvopr}}{10bp}{10bp}{true} all of the above.
\par\bigskip
\medskip\hrule height 1pt\medskip
\par\bigskip

\VOPRN. What data model does XML implement?
\par\bigskip \radioButton{button\arabic{nvopr}}{10bp}{10bp}{true} hierarchical;
\par\medskip \radioButton{button\arabic{nvopr}}{10bp}{10bp}{false} network;
\par\medskip \radioButton{button\arabic{nvopr}}{10bp}{10bp}{false} relational.
\par\bigskip
\medskip\hrule height 1pt\medskip
\par\bigskip
    
    \begin{center}
        \pushButton[\CA{Result} \A{/S/JavaScript/JS(
            var correct = 0;
            var amount = \arabic{nvopr};% 19
            var est = 0;
            for( var i = 1; i <= amount; i++ ){
                var selected = this.getField("button"+i).value;
                if(selected===true) {
                    this.getField("button"+i).textColor=color.green;
                    correct++;
                } else {
                    this.getField("button"+i).textColor=color.red;
                }
            }
            var proc = (correct*100/amount).toFixed(0);
            if (proc >= 0 && proc < 50) {
                est = 2;
            } else if (proc >= 50 && proc < 65) {
                est = 3;
            } else if (proc >= 65 && proc < 85) {
                est = 4;
            } else /* it is greater than 85 */ {
                est = 5;
            }
            app.alert('Correct answers ' + correct + ' from ' + amount + ' (' + proc + String.fromCharCode(37) + ') ' + 'Rating - ' + est);
            )}]{jsEx}{100bp}{11bp}
\hspace{5em}
\pushButton[\CA{Show answers} \A{/S/JavaScript/JS(
%
%   Show correct answers after entering password
%
)}]{jsEx}{100bp}{11bp}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prompt the user to enter a string using the `execDialog()` function. Then you can test whether this string is identical to another (the password). Upon entering the correct password, the correct answers will be selected by settig the value of the radio button group to "true".

Note, however, that this is not secure at all! Anybody who has Acrobat Pro can easily access the password since it is hard coded in the script (it is "MySecretPassword").

Also note that although all radio buttons that belong to the same group should have the same ID, it would be better to give them different values each. The two buttons should really have different IDs.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, latexsym, mathtext}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=20mm, right=20mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%----------------------------
\usepackage[pdftex]{eforms}
\everyRadioButton{}
%
\newcounter{nvopr}
\newcommand{\VOPRN}{\addtocounter{nvopr}{1}\arabic{nvopr}}%
%
\makeatletter
%
\renewcommand{\alph}[1]{\asbuk{#1}}
\setenumerate[1]{label=\arabic*), nosep, leftmargin=1.55\parindent, labelindent=\parindent, labelsep=*}
\setenumerate[2]{label=\theenumi\arabic*), nosep, leftmargin=\parindent,  listparindent=\parindent}
\makeatother
%----------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \LARGE Test\ldots
\end{center}

\VOPRN. The application of the information system implements?
\par\bigskip \radioButton{button\arabic{nvopr}}{10bp}{10bp}{false1} secure storage of information;
\par\medskip \radioButton{button\arabic{nvopr}}{10bp}{10bp}{false2} performing application-specific transformations of information and calculations;
\par\medskip \radioButton{button\arabic{nvopr}}{10bp}{10bp}{false3} providing users with a convenient interaction interface;
\par\medskip \radioButton{button\arabic{nvopr}}{10bp}{10bp}{true} all of the above.
\par\bigskip
\medskip\hrule height 1pt\medskip
\par\bigskip

\VOPRN. What data model does XML implement?
\par\bigskip \radioButton{button\arabic{nvopr}}{10bp}{10bp}{true} hierarchical;
\par\medskip \radioButton{button\arabic{nvopr}}{10bp}{10bp}{false1} network;
\par\medskip \radioButton{button\arabic{nvopr}}{10bp}{10bp}{false2} relational.
\par\bigskip
\medskip\hrule height 1pt\medskip
\par\bigskip
    
    \begin{center}
        \pushButton[\CA{Result} \A{/S/JavaScript/JS(
            var correct = 0;
            var amount = \arabic{nvopr};% 19
            var est = 0;
            for( var i = 1; i <= amount; i++ ){
                var selected = this.getField('button'+i).value;
                if(selected === true) {
                    this.getField('button'+i).textColor = color.green;
                    correct++;
                } else {
                    this.getField('button'+i).textColor = color.red;
                }
            }
            var proc = (correct*100/amount).toFixed(0);
            if (proc >= 0 && proc < 50) {
                est = 2;
            } else if (proc >= 50 && proc < 65) {
                est = 3;
            } else if (proc >= 65 && proc < 85) {
                est = 4;
            } else /* it is greater than 85 */ {
                est = 5;
            }
            app.alert('Correct answers ' + correct + ' from ' + amount + ' (' + proc + String.fromCharCode(37) + ') ' + 'Rating - ' + est);
            )}]{jsEx1}{100bp}{11bp}
\hspace{5em}
\pushButton[\CA{Show answers} \A{/S/JavaScript/JS(
var pwDlg = {
    description: {
        elements: [
            { name: "Enter password to show answers:", type: "static_text" },
            { item_id: "txt1", type: "edit_text", char_width: 50, password: true },
            { type: "ok_cancel" },
       ]
    },
    commit: function(dialog) {
        var data = dialog.store();
        this.strPw = data['txt1'];
    }
};
if(app.execDialog(pwDlg) == 'ok' && pwDlg.strPw == 'MySecretPassword') {
    var amount = \arabic{nvopr};
    for( var i = 1; i <= amount; i++ ){
        this.getField('button'+i).value = true;
        this.getField('button'+i).textColor = color.green;
        this.getField('button'+i).readonly = true;
    }   
    app.beep();
}
)}]{jsEx2}{100bp}{11bp}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(Due to the settings of my working environment, the labels in the dialog box on the picture are in German. They will be in the language of the relevant working environment of the user.)

---

To make everything a bit more opaque (but not truly secure), you can include a hashing function (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8831937/9303652)) that compares the hash of the user input with the hash of the password:

(Note that with this implementation, it might be the case that a random string accidentially results in the same hash. For better security, a secure and collision-resistant hashing algorithm such as SHA would be needed.)

```
function getHash(string) {
    var hash = 0;
    if (string.length == 0) {
        return hash;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        char = string.charCodeAt(i);
        hash = ((hash << 5) - hash) + char;
        hash = hash & hash;
    }
    return hash;
}
var pwDlg = {
    description: {
        elements: [
            { name: "Enter password to show answers:", type: "static_text" },
            { item_id: "txt1", type: "edit_text", char_width: 50, password: true },
            { type: "ok_cancel" },
       ]
    },
    commit: function(dialog) {
        var data = dialog.store();
        this.strPw = data['txt1'];
    }
};
if (app.execDialog(pwDlg) == 'ok' && getHash(pwDlg.strPw) == -904298921) {
    var amount = \arabic{nvopr};
    for (var i = 1; i <= amount; i++) {
        this.getField('button'+i).value = true;
        this.getField('button'+i).textColor = color.green;
        this.getField('button'+i).readonly = true;
    }   
    app.beep();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jasper Habicht.

Comment: How can I hide the letters in the password and display "*"? It would be convenient.

Comment: @Youra_P I changed my answer: use `password: true` as option for the relevant field,

Comment: Thank you. Last question. Is it possible to use execDialog() to display the result in a way that it is not possible to correct the answer?
Thanks again, @Jasper Habicht.

Comment: @Youra_P Yes, you could add `this.getField('button'+i).readonly = true;` for example.

Comment: With a hash function, a great solution. Everything is working. The previous question is about replacing app.alert with app.execDialog. How to pass test result string to execDialog and not allow it to be edited? @Jasper Habicht

Comment: @Youra_P Hm, you can add `this.getField('button'+i).readonly = true;` to the other function that calculates the result as well (after `var selected = this.getField('button'+i).value;`). You don't need to change the `app.alert` to `app.execDialog` then.

Comment: Thank you very much @Jasper Habicht!